Knights, Knaves and Jokers with Layers (part 3)
So, you escaped the third room. Your ice cold logic has sent the overlords into a fiery hot anger.
You enter the room and see five gentlemen. You sigh, and look up at the roof. "Is this all you can do? Add a new joker every room?"
A stubby and meek imp appears before you, hat in hand. "Please... I am on trial before the higher overlords; this is my chance to prove myself... and you are painting me a fool."
"Because you are."
"Please, either continue trying to solve my puzzles... or at least tell me how they can be harder!"
You smile. "Ask me to prove the general case, doofus."
A smile breaks across the imp's face like a bolt of lighting. "YIPPE!!!!"

In front of you is a knight (always telling the truth), a knave (always lying) and $n-2$ jokers (always answering yes or no randomly). We call these $n$ gentlemen "$n$-tuple $A$", and you don't know who is who.
Behind them are $\displaystyle \binom{3 + n -1}n = x$ different $n$-tuples, labelled $B_1$ to $B_x$. Each $n$-tuple is a set of knights, knaves and jokers, where the full set of $n$-tuples is the set of all combinations of knights, knaves and jokers, allowing for repetitions.
Behind the $x$ different $n$-tuples are two doors: door 1 and 2. One leads to freedom, and one to death, but you don't know which. Your goal is to guarantee your escape by asking yes-or-no questions to the knights, knaves and jokers, to which they will answer either yes or no. However, there are some rules:

You can only direct a question to a single knight/knave/joker at a time.
You cannot ask a member of $n$-tuple $A$ any questions regarding the doors.
Once you ask a question of a member of an $n$-tuple $B_i$, you cannot pose a question to a member of any other $n$-tuple.
Paradoxical questions, or questions about the future, will not be answered by anyone; joker, knight or knave.

Prove which values of $n$ the puzzle is solvable for and which values it is not; and for the values it is solvable for, give a solution having the lowest maximum of questions used.

This is a partial answer only addressing solvability!
The amount of information that can be gathered using the A-tuple

 One can ask a question such that knights and knaves answer the same, e.g. Do the questions "Are you a knight?" and "Is person X a joker?" have the same answer?
 One can ask such a question to all persons in tuple A about all persons in all tuples B.

Dependable patterns

 A potentially 'dependable' answering pattern of an A-person (one which it can be given by a knight/knave) has:
 1 B-tuple with n+2 jokers, 2 B-tuples with n+1 jokers, 3 B-tuples with n jokers etc.
 Note that exactly 1/3 of all B-persons will then be identified as joker.
 Such a pattern can be discarded if it only one A-person produces it, since the patterns of the knight and knave will be the same.
 So worst case we end up with (n+2)/2 potentially 'dependable' answering patterns.

Disjunct patterns make the problem unsolvable

 Assume every b-tuple has a pair of 'disjunct' patterns, i.e. has no person in it that is a knight/knave in both of the 2 patterns.
 Then we must use such a tuple to find the door.
 The designated knights/knaves according the both patterns can answer consistently without violating the consistency of the other pattern; this since they are jokers there.
 Since one may be the actual truth, the problem is unsolvable.

The maximum of disjunct b-tuples for a pair of patterns

 A pair of patters can be disjunct in just above 50% of the B-tuples by matching the amount of jokers as follows:
$(0,n+2)(1,n+1)(2,n)...(n+2,0)$
 This can be done $1+2+3+...+1$ times
 for odd n=2k+1 this is  $k*(k+1)+k*(k+1) /(2k*(2k+1)) = (k+1)/(2k+1)$
 for even n=2k this is   $k*(k-1)+k*(k+1) /((2k-1)*2k) = k/(2k-1)$

Insolvability lower bound

 If we have 4 (or more) potentially 'dependable' answering patterns, the first 2 can be disjunct in the first half of the b-tuples, and the second 2 can be disjunct in the remaining b-tuples.
 Thus the problem is unsolvable for 6+ jokers in a tuple.

Solvability upper bound

 If we have  3 potentially 'dependable' answering patterns then is a b-tuple without disjunctness of 2 patterns.
 proof:
 If there is a B-person that is identified as knight/knave in all three patterns, there is no disjuctness , and that person can be used to find the door.
 Else every B-person is a joker according to at least 1 pattern, and because exactly 1/3 is identified as joker every B-person is a joker according to exactly 1 pattern.
 Patterns have (n+3) out of (n+3)*(n+4)/2  tuples without jokers, less than a third for n = 4 or 5.
 So there is a B-tuple that has at least joker according to all three patterns.

 Now focus on three persons: P1 a joker (only) according to pattern 1, P2 a joker (only) according to pattern 2, P3 a joker (only) according to pattern 3.
 use P1 to find out if P2 is a joker.
 If P2 is identified as joker, P3 cannot be a joker and can be used to find the door.
 If P2 is identified as not a joker, P2 cannot be a joker  and can be used to find the door.
 So the problem is solvable


What about asking the first gentleman if the on to the right is a knight, then ask the second gentleman the same thing, asking the third, then the fourth, and to the fifth ask if the one on the left is a knight. After, tally the results and to the one who said no, ask which door is death? This is probably very wrong, but that is five questions.

On this site, we expect answers to explain why they are correct, instead of just making guesses. Please [edit] to elaborate on why this strategy would work.
